# Why should I symlink my dotfiles when backing up to Git repo?

Tags: configuration, git, github

I've been struggling to learn the best way to back up my dotfiles to a git repo, but every tutorial out there seems to have very different methods. One consistency I've found across the methods, though, is that they almost always place their dotfiles in a new directory and then symlink them back to the Home directory.

Why is this? Why not just create a new git repo in Home itself and have it only add dotfiles?

Also, is there no better or easier way to do this? We really need to create scripts and everything just to sync and restore out dotfiles?